# Create UI Flat button for objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I would like to create a flat button with a background color of `#E74C3C`

Here is the code I have so far:

```
[UIColor colorWithRed: 0.906 green: 0.298 blue: 0.235 alpha: 1];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want your button in your storyboard first. Then, in your `ViewController` file, ensure that you have an `IBOutlet` for your button.

*in your .h file under interface*

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
```

*in your .m file under implementation*

```
@synthesize myButton;
```

Once you have this defined as a property, you can set the colour of your button in your `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAppear` like so:

```
myButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.906 green: 0.298 blue: 0.235 alpha: 1];
```

or

```
[myButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed: 0.906 green: 0.298 blue: 0.235 alpha: 1]];
```

Once you're done this, make sure to connect the outlet in your storyboard: information on that is available in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_connections/chapters/CreatingOutlet.html).

For rounding the corner of the button, just do the following:

```
myButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```

Comment: thanks very much one more thing how do i make this button round , do i use cg rect?

Comment: I updated the answer with how to do that as well. Happy coding!

Answer (score 4):

```
UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, 40)];
btn.backgroundColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed: 0.906 green: 0.298 blue: 0.235 alpha: 1];
[btn setTitle:@"Test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:btn];
```

Comment: it you take button in storyboard then you have to take @IBOutlet in .h file of viewcontroller 
for better understanding how to take IBOutlet please see video in Youtube

Comment: and if already taken @iboutlet then you just replace btn with your IBOutlet object

Answer (score 2):

## 0 lines of code

[image: Picker]

You are new to iOS development? Do things right from the get go:

1. Use **Interface Builder**
2. Use **Storyboard**
3. Take advantage of technology that is available to you, do not program on your hands and knees.

[image: IB]